# Apache: After disabling SSLv3 for POODLE, can't connect with openssl or java without first specifying -tls1

Tags: linux, openssl, apache-2.4, poodle

Recently we updated our mod_ssl config to disable SSLv3 for the POODLE attack, and that seems to be working. However, old clients (java 1.6 apps of ours, openssl 0.9.8za on my mac) get a handshake error, unless we specify TLSv1 in the code/command line respectively. However, from the same clients, I can initiate an SSL connection fine from those same tools to i.e. facebook.com, which also has SSLv3 disabled.

Symptom:

```
#working example site with SSLv3 disabled:
My-iMac:~ me$ openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
....

#My site with SSLv3 disabled:
My-iMac:~ me$ openssl s_client -connect site.company.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
66904:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:182:

#Same site, now with -tls1 on command line, works:
My-iMac:~ me$ openssl s_client -connect site.company.com:443 -tls1
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
....
```

My question - what can I do to let this and other clients connect/negotiate properly, automatically (like facebook.com), without having to specify tls1? Is this some known limitation of the version of openssl in RHEL5/Centos5?

Server setup:
Centos 5.x, latest openssl rpm (openssl-0.9.8e-31.el5_11), custom built apache 2.4.10

Relevant apache config:

```
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1
  SSLHonorCipherOrder On
  SSLCipherSuite RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!AESGCM:!SSLV2:!eNULL
  SSLCertificateFile /opt/ca/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/ca/cert.pem
```

Comment: Thanks much for this, definitely looks like the issue at hand, and obviously I didn't know quite what I was looking for.